# Loopback How to get a method path programmatically

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a remote method called `Model.showMap' for my model, this method is implemented by many models. but I need build a url internally to send a email.

How I can get the method programmatically? I need something like

```
ModelA.showMaṕ.getPath({id: XXXX, absolute: true}); // http://localhost:3000/api/ModelA/xxxx/mymap
People.showMaṕ.getPath({id: XXXX, absolute: true}); // http://localhost:3000/api/people/xxxx/mymap
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the remoting metadata as follows:

> Model.sharedClass.find('showMap', true).http.path;

Comment: Thanks for the clue, will be lots of help to understand better loopback but this only returns me the last part of the method `/mymap`

Answer (score 0):

Using Raymond's answer I'll expand a bit

```
return [
  Model.sharedClass.http.path,
  Model.sharedClass.find('showMap', true).http.path
].join(''); //Model/mymap
```

In this case solved my problem but would be great if loopback support this by default also passing parameters